# Why did my local git tag go from "hello" to "hello-1-48281"

Tags: git, bash, tags, git-tag

```
$ git tag hello

$ git describe --tags
hello

... work work ...
$ git commit -m "work stuff"

$ git describe --tags
hello-1-48281
```

Say what? What's the extra stuff? Doesn't look like a SHA1... is it possible to just get "hello" back?

Comment: Your current HEAD is not the tag "hello".  Why would you want git describe to lie to you and tell you that it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Say what? What's the extra stuff? Doesn't look like a SHA1... is it possible to just get "hello" back?

"git describe" probably doesn't do what you think it does:

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>   The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit.
>   If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown. Otherwise,
>   it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional commits on top
>   of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of the most recent
>   commit.
> ```

So, in your example of "hello-1-48281", git is saying, "the `hello` tag is separated by 1 commit from the current object, which is `48281`."

If you want a list of tags instead, just do `git tag -l`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I blame my lack of sleep for not realizing that a commit of course put me at a different state. However, I want to put the current tag in my bash prompt, and if I diverge from the tag, I don't want to have a ahead-of-tag label in there. Is there a git command that will return if you are exactly on any tag?

Comment: Should have man'd up, `git describe --tags --exact` is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `git describe` man page, it's described in there.

The first number is number of commits between (in your example) the current commit and the tag.

The second should be `g` plus an abbreviated SH1 of the current commit. Not sure how you got that number without `g`, I can't reproduce that here.